# Mejores prácticas de parsear un json sin key

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, parsear

Que tal a todos hoy me mandaron un json, que no tiene un key. Y me resultado complicado poder parsear..

```
{  
   "registrarEmpresa":[
      {  
         "imagen":"imagen",
         "nombre_empresa":"Emp",
         "pais":"Arabia Saudita",
         "ciudad":"Callao",
         "email":"mail emp",
         "tipo_empresa":"2",
         "anio_fundacion":"2000",
         "descripcion":"ansjnsdess",
         "nombre":"User",
         "apellido":"Ape",
         "cargo":"Car",
         "telefono":"49494994",
         "celular":"73733737",
         "email_usuario":"mail",
         "website":"eeb",
         "linkedin":"lin"
      },
      [  
         {  
            "sector_emp":"Servicios"
         },
         {  
            "sector_emp":"Industria textil y confecciones"
         },
         {  
            "sector_emp":"Ropa industrial y accesorios"
         }
      ],
      [  
         {  
            "producto":"pepa"
         },
         {  
            "producto":"pick"
         }
      ],
      [  
         {  
            "certificacion":"GLUTEN FREE"
         },
         {  
            "certificacion":"HACCP"
         },
         {  
            "certificacion":"HALAL"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

**Sólo obtengo y muestro lo que mando de esta forma**

```
$json = new stdClass();
$json->type = "registrarUsuario";
$json->action = "insert";
$json->status = FALSE;

$data               = new stdClass();

$data->datos                = json_encode($this->input->post('registrarEmpresa'));
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Me gustaría poder parsear la lista que contiene sector_emp, producto y certificación pero no logro realizarlo, el punto es que debería regresar esos datos para poder verificar y lograr regresarlos concatenados
por ejm.

```
Servicios, Industria textil y confecciones, Ropa industrial y accesorios.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución es convirtiendo el `json` en una [`matriz asociativa` (json_decode($jsonText, true))](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

Por ejemplo:

```
$json = new stdClass();
$json->type = "registrarUsuario";
$json->action = "insert";
$json->status = FALSE;

// Indicando `true` como segundo parámetro obtenemos una matriz asociativa.
$datos = json_decode($this->input->post('registrarEmpresa'), true);

// Sectores
$secores = $datos['registrarEmpresa'][1];
$temp = array();
foreach ($secores as $info) {
    $temp[] = $info['sector_emp'];
}
$json->sectors = implode(', ', $temp);

// Productos
$productos = $datos['registrarEmpresa'][2];
$temp = array();
foreach ($productos as $info) {
    $temp[] = $info['producto'];
}
$json->products = implode(', ', $temp);

// Certificaciones
$certificaciones = $datos['registrarEmpresa'][3];
$temp = array();
foreach ($certificaciones as $info) {
    $temp[] = $info['certificacion'];
}
$json->certifications = implode(', ', $temp);


header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eres el men !

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente tendrías que hacer un `json_decode()` de ese json e iterar por los elementos de la segunda, tercera y cuarta posición del `array` que te devolverá, concatenándolos como deseas.

Comment: Si en eso estoy.. pero no logro obtener los datos como lista ` [{  
            "sector_emp":"Servicios"
         },
         {  
            "sector_emp":"Industria textil y confecciones"
         },
         {  
            "sector_emp":"Ropa industrial y accesorios"
         }]`